# tf.layers.Conv1D vs tf.keras.layers.Conv1D

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I was using [`tf.layers.conv1d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) found in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) tutorial but then realised it's been deprecated. Then I discovered [`tf.layers.Conv1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D) and [`tf.keras.layers.Conv1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D). I understand the later one is the keras implementation of one dimensional convolutional layer. I'm however not sure which one to use and what's the difference in terms of functionality. It would be great of someone could point out examples of using any of these two where the input data comes from csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Layers API is deprecated and will be removed from TF 2.0. `keras.layers` is a direct substitute, because it will be the main high level api for future version. 
As per official docs, `tf.layers` are wrappers around `tf.keras.layers`. Convolutional layers in Layers API inherit from `tf.keras.layers`. From [tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L28):

```
@tf_export('layers.Conv1D')
class Conv1D(keras_layers.Conv1D, base.Layer):
  """1D convolution layer (e.g. temporal convolution).
```

TensorFlow layers cannot be used directly within a Keras model, as it they miss some attributes required by the Keras API. However, it is possible to use them  with Keras Lambda layer.